# Чтение данных из syscall.RawConn golang

Tags: golang

Есть tcp сервер. Мне нужно получить данные из syscall.RawConn. Я пытаюсь это сделать таким образом:

```
for {
    for _, conn := range tcpConns {
        rawConn, err := conn.SyscallConn()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("get raw conn error: %s\n", err)
        }
        rawConn.Read(readConn)
    }
}

func readConn(fd uintptr) bool {
    f := os.NewFile(fd, "file")
    b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(f)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("read file error: %s\n", err)
        return false
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("New data: %s\n", string(b))
        return true
    }
}
```

при выполнении, в терминале я наблюдаю:

```
read file error: read file: resource temporarily unavailable
```

т.е. эту ошибку возвращает `ioutil.ReadAll(f)`. Далее функция `readConn` возвращает false и выполнение программы блочится. Т.е. код не идёт дальше `rawConn.Read(readConn)`, хотя моя функция была выполнена и вернула результат. В документации говорится что в случае, когда readConn возвращает false будет предпринято ещё несколько попыток прочитать данные, когда это станет возможно. Но ничего не происходит и не понятно что значит "когда это станет возможно".

Я пробовал возвращать true в любом случае в функции `readConn` но тогда выполнение блочится на втором круге бесконечного цикла на строке `ioutil.ReadAll(f)`. Что я должен сделать чтобы получить данные?

Я знаю что можно не получать `syscall.RawConn` и читать из net.TCPConn, но мне не нравится что там нужно создавать по горутине для каждого соединения и оно жрёт много памяти, поэтому я хочу сделать 1 бесконечный цикл который будет читать данные из всех соединений без горутин

Comment: горутина жрет 2 килобайта. это разве много?

Comment: conn - это net.Conn ? у этого объекта нет функции SyscallConn(). а что за объект readConn?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor conn это net.TCPConn, readConn это функция, она в моём коде объявлена

Comment: функция выглядит как `Read(b []byte) (n int, err error)`, она принимает массив байт, никак не получится передать туда readConn функция. все таки, подскажите точно что за структура `rawConn` или приложите воспроизводящий пример

Comment: @SeniorPomidor Нет, функция Read принимает именно функцию, никакой не массив байт: https://pkg.go.dev/syscall#RawConn

Comment: `RawConn.Read` не подходит для вашей цели. Эта функция реализует блокирующее чтение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go создаёт сокеты в неблокирующем режиме. Если данных нет, то системный вызов `read` возвращает ошибку `EAGAIN`, которую Go снабжает тестовым сообщением `resource temporarily unavailable`

Если эту ошибку проигнорировать, то `rawConn` работает.

NB. Если вы пользуетесь `RawConn.Read`, то вам не нужно вызывать `ReadAll` -- `RawConn.Read` блокируется, то есть будет вызывать вашу функцию `readConn` до тех пор, пока функция не вернёт `true`.

> Read invokes f on the underlying connection's file     descriptor or
> handle; f is expected to try to read from the      file descriptor.    If
> f returns true, Read returns. Otherwise Read blocks    waiting for the
> connection to be ready for reading and     tries again repeatedly.     The
> file descriptor is guaranteed to remain valid while f      executes but
> not after f returns.

Пример использования `RawConn.Read`. Программа читает из файлового дескриптора сокета системным вызовом `syscall.Read`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    addr, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", "localhost:54321")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Address resolution failed:", err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    l, err := net.ListenTCP("tcp", addr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error listening:", err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    // Close the listener when the application closes.
    defer l.Close()
    fmt.Println("Listening on ", addr)

    conn, err := l.AcceptTCP()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Accept failed: ", err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    rawConn, err := conn.SyscallConn()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("get raw conn error: %s\n", err)
    }

    rawConn.Read(readConnWithSyscall)
}

func readConnWithSyscall(fd uintptr) (done bool) {
    fmt.Println("readConn: file descriptor:", fd)
    byteBuf := make([]byte, 1024)

    n, err := syscall.Read(int(fd), byteBuf)
    if err != nil {
        if err == syscall.EAGAIN {
            println("readconn: EAGAIN")
            // Try once more
            return false
        } else {
            println("read: error ", err)
            return true
        }
    }
    if n > 0 {
        println("readconn: read", n, "bytes: ", string(byteBuf[:n]))
        // More left to read
        return false
    } else {
        // read returned 0 == EOF
        println("readconn: finished")
        return true
    }
}
```

Тестовый запуск `echo "Test" | nc -N -w 1 -v localhost 54321`
Серверная программа вывела:

```
Listening on  127.0.0.1:54321
readConn: file descriptor: 7
readconn: EAGAIN
readConn: file descriptor: 7
readconn: read 5 bytes:  Test

readConn: file descriptor: 7
readconn: finished
```

**UPDATE**

Асинхронный читатель из сокета. Этот вариант не блокирует `RawConn.Read`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
    "syscall"
)

type asyncReader struct {
    data []byte
    done bool
}

func (r *asyncReader) Read(fd uintptr) (done bool) {
    byteBuf := make([]byte, 1024)
    done = true

    n, err := syscall.Read(int(fd), byteBuf)
    if err != nil {
        if err == syscall.EAGAIN {
            println("asyncReader: EAGAIN")
        } else {
            println("asyncReader: error ", err)
            r.done = true
        }
    } else if n > 0 {
        println("asyncReader: read", n, "bytes: ", string(byteBuf[:n]))
        r.data = append(r.data, byteBuf[:n]...)
    } else {
        // read returned 0 == EOF
        println("asyncReader: finished")
        r.done = true
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    addr, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", "localhost:54321")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Address resolution failed:", err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    l, err := net.ListenTCP("tcp", addr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error listening:", err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    // Close the listener when the application closes.
    defer l.Close()
    fmt.Println("Listening on ", addr)

    conn, err := l.AcceptTCP()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Accept failed: ", err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    rawConn, err := conn.SyscallConn()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("get raw conn error: %s\n", err)
    }

    // rawConn.Read(readConnWithSyscall)
    r := &asyncReader{done: false, data: make([]byte, 0)}
    for !r.done {
        rawConn.Read(r.Read)
        println("main: data size:", len(r.data))
    }

    println("main: received:", string(r.data))
}
```

Пример - клиент посылает одну строку, потом ждёт секунду и посылает ещё строку:

```
{ echo "Test 1"; sleep 1; echo "Test 2"; } | nc -N -w 1 -v localhost 54321
```

Сервер:

```
Listening on  127.0.0.1:54321
asyncReader: EAGAIN
main: data size: 0
asyncReader: EAGAIN
main: data size: 0
asyncReader: EAGAIN
main: data size: 0
asyncReader: EAGAIN
main: data size: 0
asyncReader: EAGAIN
main: data size: 0
asyncReader: read 7 bytes:  Test 1

main: data size: 7
asyncReader: EAGAIN
main: data size: 7
.
.
.
asyncReader: read 7 bytes:  Test 2

main: data size: 14
.
.
.
asyncReader: finished
main: data size: 14
main: received: Test 1
Test 2
```

В троеточиях спрятались 90 тысяч (!) вызовов асинхронного читателя.

Основной недостаток - этот вариант грузит CPU на 100%, так как постоянно дёргает сокет.

Для по-настоящему асинхронной обработки нескольких сокетов без избыточных запросов нужно пользоваться [`syscall.Select`](https://pkg.go.dev/syscall#Select) или [`syscall.EpollWait`](https://pkg.go.dev/syscall#EpollWait)

Comment: пришел, чтобы ответить, а ответ дан уже за 20 секунд до этого (( хороший ответ, палец вверх!

Comment: А если я при EAGAIN верну true? Это вроде должно работать?

Comment: @Inventor можно, конечно. Но для этого нужно придумать, как отличить EAGAIN от EOF. В принципе, это реально сделать. Например, если вызывать не `readConn` а некоторое замыкание анонимной функции с указателем на внешнюю переменную, в которую функция будет писать что именно случилось.

Comment: а `if err == syscall.EAGAIN` разве не поможет мне отличить?

Comment: @Inventor как вы отличите на уровне, где вызывается `rawConn.Read(readConn)`? Вызовы `rawConn.Read` всегда возвращают `nil`.

Comment: Понял проблему, тогда думаю бесконечный цикл и readConn сделаю методами одной и той же структуры, а соединения хранить в поле структуры, чтобы из readConn иметь доступ к соединению

Comment: @Inventor я добавил вариант с асинхронным чтением сокета в ответ. Но это не выход - загрузка ядра 100%. Если вы хотите, чтобы функция чтения вызывалась только тогда, когда в сокете что-то есть, то нужно программировать напрямую через `epoll`.